# php yii framework populate CActiveform dropdownlist data by model directly?

Tags: php, forms, yii, associative-array, dropdownbox

i am newbee in yii and i am learning at this moment ...

I am using in model this query to get assosiative array for my listbox

```
public function getAllCategories()
{


    $cats = $this->model()->findAll(array('select'=>'id,name'));
    $mainarr = array();

    foreach($cats as $obj)
        $mainarr["$obj->id"]=$obj->name;

    return $mainarr;
}
```

and on my form i am calling this function in my dropdownlist as this

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'name',$model->getAllCategories());  ?>
```

I have so many drop down with many different queries and i dont find any faster way to do that and everytime i have to create above array to make it fulfill. Kindly advise me better and faster solution to populate if there is any using CActiveForm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faster way, i'm not sure there is any other.

But you could reduce your code, using [`CHtml::listData();`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listData-detail) function. Atleast you'll reduce having to define a function in the model class:

```php
<?php 
    echo $form->dropDownList($model,
      'name',
      CHtml::listData(Modelname::model()->findAll(),'id','name')// $model->getAllCategories()
    );
?>
```

`listData();` will get you that associative array with `array('id'=>'name')` format.

**Edit:**

To follow good mvc practices, you could use listData in the controller action, which displays this form, instead of the form view directly:

```php
public function actionFormDisplayer(){
  // other code
  $list_for_name_dropdown = CHtml::listData(Modelname::model()->findAll(),'id','name');
  // other code
  // then in render pass this value also
  $this->render('viewname',
     array('dropdownoptions'=>$list_for_name_dropdown, // other data to pass
  ));
}
```

Then in your view you can use `$dropdownoptions`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display menu name in dropdown from menu mode then use this code
            $menu_model = Menu::model()->findAll();
            $list = CHtml::listData($menu_model, 'menu_id', 'menu_name');
            echo CHtml::dropDownList('categories', $category, $list,  array('empty' => '(Select a category'));  `